# Angularjs - Check if controller modal mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

My angular app has a controller that can be used both in modal mode and in no modal mode. I would like to check in which mode it is. Can someone help me ?

**Order controller**

```
    $scope.chooseClient = function() {
        $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'partials/client/edit.html',
            controller: 'ClientEditController',
       }).result.then(function (client) {
            // Modal OK
            if (client) {
                $scope.model.client = client;
            }    
       }, function (status) {
            // Modal cancelado
       });
    };
```

**Client controller**

```
.controller('ClientEditController',
    function ($scope, $location) {

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            if (//I would check if modal mode) {
                $scope.$dismiss('cancel');
            } else {
                $location.path("/client/list");
            }    
        };



});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a simpler way but according to [this doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs) you should at least be able to check if the `openedClass` is applied to your element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a `resolve` object with a flag. That will force you to pass the same resolve in your route for the controller, and inject to resolve to the controller.

```
$scope.chooseClient = function() {
    $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'partials/client/edit.html',
        controller: 'ClientEditController',
        resolve: {
            isModal: true
        }
   }).result.then(function (client) {
        // Modal OK
        if (client) {
            $scope.model.client = client;
        }    
   }, function (status) {
        // Modal cancelado
   });
};
```

And than check:

```
.controller('ClientEditController', function ($scope, $location, isModal) {
    $scope.cancel = function() {
        if (isModal) {
           $scope.$dismiss('cancel');
        } else {
            $location.path("/client/list");
        }    
    };
});
```

See docs: [$uibModal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)